# Polymer 2.x show toast if service-worker update available

Tags: polymer, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, polymer-2.x

The service-worker is registered in `index.html`. How do I show a toast message if an update is available?

As far as I can see I have two possibilities to show a notification:

1. Call a function from the shell, but at the moment when I register the service-worker the shell is not yet loaded.
2. Import paper-toast into index.html, but I do not know how it would work.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `index.html` where the service worker is registered use the following

```
 if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js').then(function (registration) {

      var app = document.querySelector('#app');
      if (registration.waiting) {
        app.update(registration);
        return;
      }

      if (registration.installing) {
        registration.installing.addEventListener('statechange', function () {
          app.update(registration);
        });
        return;
      }

      registration.addEventListener('updatefound', function () {
        app.update(registration);
      });

      console.info('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
    }, function (err) {
      console.info('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
    });;
  });
}
```

Notice that app is variable which holds a reference to your shell element
usually named `<my-app></my-app>` in `index.html`

Now you can define the `udpate` method inside your shell element and the `paper-toast`

```
<paper-toast id="updateToast" duration="0" text="New Update Is Here :)">
  <paper-button onclick="window.location.reload(true)">
        Update
  </paper-button>
  <paper-button onclick="updateToast.toggle()">
      Cancel
  </paper-button>
</paper-toast>

 // update function
 update: function (worker) {
    this.$.updateToast.show();
 },
```

Comment: Thanks, however var app = document.querySelector('#app'); returns null for me. Why? Inside the index.html the service-worker gets registered, then the shell is imported, then there is the <my-app></my-app> inside of the body tag.

Comment: You need to give you shell element an id which in this case "app" . `<myapp id="app"></my-app>`

Comment: But the shell is initialized after the service-worker is registered. This is a template from polymer2, do I have to change this?

Comment: No problem with this , just give the shell an ID

Comment: Thanks. The ID works now. Just the cancel does not work. It tells me that updateToast is not defined after clicking cancel.

Comment: Hmmm, strange, you can create a function to be called on click instead, I mean something simple like `hideToast(){this.$.updateToast.toggle()}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164819/discussion-between-hyyan-abo-fakher-and-user2799180).